# How to handle dynamic folder with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Having an php api located in `/api/index.php` which takes different modules and values like this:

`api/index.php?module=base&sum=3`

`api/index.php?module=ui&eff=abe3`

at the moment I only have a module and one value.
I can't handle it to write the mod_rewrite

i want to get the following:

`api/base/sum/3 -> /api/index.php?module=base&sum=3`

`api/ui/eff/abe3 -> /api/index.php?module=ui&eff=abe3`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let you know that we solved it like this:

RewriteRule    ^api/basement(/)*/door1(/)*(close|open)*?$    index.php?module=basement&door1=$3   [NC,L]